# change the string of dictionary list value to running code

Tags: c#, winforms

```
  Dictionary<string, string> RoleName = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  RoleName.Add("Admin", "toolStripMenuItem1.Enabled=true");
  RoleName.Add("Manager", "toolStripMenuItem2.Enabled = true");
  RoleName.Add("usero","btn.Enabled=true" );
  RoleName.Add("customer", "btnorder.Enabled = true");
 
  var t = contains the list of roles of the user in Database
  foreach (var itemList in RoleName)
            {
                foreach (var itemdbRole in t)
                {
                    if (itemList.Key == itemdbRole.Name)
                    {
                      
      CSharpCodeProvider cs = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>());
      CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" });
      parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;   
      CompilerResults results = cs.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, itemList.Value);               }
       }
   }
```

In the above code I want to execute the "value" in the dictionary list if it satisfied the conditions, I had used that code but it doesn't work, if anyone have better solution, as I want to execute the string in the dictionary's value as code, another issue using two for statements I think it consume more time any better way to check if the value of one list exists in the another list
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you expect "toolStripMenuItem1.Enabled=true" to do if executed? It looks like it is supposed to act on some field named "toolStripMenuItem1" embedded in an instance of some form, but how do you expect it to know which form? What do you expect it to do it `toolStripMenuItem1` doesn't actually exist? Or if it doesn't have an enabled property?

Comment: @JohnWu thank you for your respond, toolStripMenuItem1 is dropdown menu(  toolStripMenuItem) on the same form which is Form2 , I have menu items I want to show them to  the users based on their roles, and menu items exists on the same Form2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store controls instead of strings in the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Component> RoleName = new Dictionary<string, Component>
    {
        { "Admin", toolStripMenuItem1 },
        { "Manager", toolStripMenuItem2 },
        { "user", btn },
        { "customer", btnorder }
    };

// Disable all controls from the dictionary
toolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
toolStripMenuItem2.Enabled = false;
btn.Enabled = false;
btnorder.Enabled = false;

var rolesFromDB = "Admin,user";
foreach (var role in rolesFromDB.Split(','))
{
    if (RoleName.TryGetValue(role, out var component))
    {
        switch (component)
        {
            case ToolStripItem tItem:
                tItem.Enabled = true;
                break;
            case Control control:
                control.Enabled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the [`ToolStripItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem?view=net-5.0) doesn't inherit [`Control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=net-5.0), we have to store controls as a [`Component`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component?view=net-5.0) in the dictionary.

Comment: thank you for your answer it is great, worked with buttons but not with  toolstripmenu  items ,

Comment: @NAZHUMASH I've updated the answer. Please revise.